# Set up PHPMyAdmin subdomain in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

For my CodeIgniter site, I would like to be able to access the database via phpMyAdmin.  I'm not sure how to set it up so I can do tripmatcher.herokuapp.com/phpmyadmin.  I have downloaded the latest stable version of phpMyAdmin, however how do I go through the process so I can log in and access the production database (I've been given some credentials for accessing a pre-existing database)? I'm not really sure where to start with this.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to work out how to integrate phpMyAdmin, so that after a heroku deploy, I can do tripmatcher.herokuapps.com/phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

I would discourage you from trying to integrate phpMyAdmin with CodeIgniter and instead would suggest that you accomplish this using a web server directive.  For instance, I use Apache. When I install PHPMyAdmin on my Ubuntu servers, I usually use the package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

On Ubuntu/Debian, this package installation usually results in the phpmyadmin source being installed at **/usr/share/phpmyadmin** and an apache conf file being installed at **/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf**. I just delete the conf file and then add this directive to the file **/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf** *so that phpmyadmin can only be accessed via HTTPS*. You may need to edit a different web configuration file on your system.

```
    # *adapted* from the phpmyadmin.conf installed
    # by the debian package (/etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf)
    # NOTE this stuff represents a pretty significant juggling of the originally
    # installed directives
    # see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=4516840#post4516840
    Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            DirectoryIndex index.php

            <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
                    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
                    php_flag track_vars On
                    php_flag register_globals Off
                    php_value include_path .
            </IfModule>
            <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
                    AuthType Basic
                    AuthName "phpMyAdmin"
                    AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
            </IfModule>
            Require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

This directive specifies an alias so that requests for **https://example.com/phpmyadmin** will be served from the files in /usr/share/phpmyadmin.

It also specifies that one must authenticate to access these files so you have to use the htpasswd file from the command line to create a user/password entry in the file /var/www/.htpasswd:

```
sudo htpasswd -c /var/www/.htpasswd some_user_name
```

That command will prompt you for a password and it will truncate and over-write the contents of /var/www/.htpassd.

**Almost forgot!** You have to restart or reload apache when making changes to its conf files.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I only have a mac currently, is it possible to set all that up with just a mac please?

Comment: @MichaelNares Hm. If you are running MAMP, the edits to the apache conf files might also apply, but Macs have no apt-get command. There are a lot of google results for 'install phpmyadmin on a mac.' Including this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DowYqkKE6SE - The instructions in this video tell you to download the source into your webroot, which might seem a little weird with CodeIgniter at first, but should be fine.

Comment: @MichaelNares - when i say it'll be 'fine' with CodeIgniter, I'm assuming that you either have a proper .htaccess file OR you don't bother with the pretty URLs and have no .htaccess file.

Comment: I'm not running any kind of web server locally, I just use Heroku to deploy.

Comment: Please clarify:  you have files on your mac that you upload to a virtual server hosted via Heroku?  If that's the case, you should be able to follow the instructions in the youtube video.  Download the phpmyadmin source, save it in your public/html directory as instructed, and make the requested config changes. You may encounter some difficulty if your server is using rewrite (.htaccess) for pretty urls, but not if things are set up properly.

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136368/discussion-between-michael-nares-and-s-imp).